# Why does LinkedIn v2 Share API give not enough permissions error on any v2/shares endpoint?

Tags: php, permissions, linkedin-api

When I make a call to any v2 LinkedIn share API  endpoint such as https://api.linkedin.com/v2/socialActions/{share URN}?oauth2_access_token={access token} I get a response saying "Not enough permissions to access /socialActions/{target} GET ".

[image: Default Application Permissions]

Our application was recently given access to marketing API which is how I got the r_ad_campaigns permission. The [share API documentation](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/guide/v2/shares/network-update-social-actions) gives no explanation of why this error would occur or what permissions I may be missing. Has anyone been able to successfully make a request to this endpoint or a similar /shares endpoint?

Comment: I am also facing the same problem, did u find any solution to this?

Comment: Also "subscribing" in case you found a solution. Additionally, do you know what kind of approvals (if any) are required to use the V2 API? I've been trying any endpoint I can find, but I'm getting permissions errors on all of them...

Comment: I'm subscribing to the thread as well.

Comment: Did you have a workable solutions guys?

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Though it's not clear from the documentation, LinkedIn API is private. You need to request authorisation from them: https://developer.linkedin.com/partner-programs